# Hermitian matrix decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Problem:**

For any positive semi-definite Hermitian matrix $A$ of rank $r\geq1$ and $\text{tr}(A)=1$, is it always possible to find matrix $P$ so that
    $$r A=P^\dagger P,$$
where $P$ is consisted of row vectors $p_i$ satisfying $\text{norm}(p_i)=1$.

---

**My attempt:**

I tested the simplest case that $A=\text{diag}(\alpha,1-\alpha)$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. It turned out that 
    $$
P=\begin{pmatrix}
  \sqrt{\alpha} & \sqrt{1-\alpha} \\
  \sqrt{\alpha} & -\sqrt{1-\alpha} \\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$
satisfied
    $$
\begin{pmatrix}
  \sqrt{\alpha} & \sqrt{1-\alpha} \\
  \sqrt{\alpha} & -\sqrt{1-\alpha} \\
\end{pmatrix}^\dagger
\begin{pmatrix}
  \sqrt{\alpha} & \sqrt{1-\alpha} \\
  \sqrt{\alpha} & -\sqrt{1-\alpha} \\
\end{pmatrix}
=2\begin{pmatrix}
  \alpha & 0 \\
   0 & 1-\alpha \\
 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Note that $P$ may not be unique since
    $$
Q=\begin{pmatrix}
  -\sqrt{\alpha} & \sqrt{1-\alpha} \\
  -\sqrt{\alpha} & -\sqrt{1-\alpha} \\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$
also do the job. In fact, for this simplest $A$, there are $8$ different $P$'s.

Besides, I also tested that this result stands for the general two-by-two matrix case.

I have checked various matrix decomposition but I still do not have any clue. Any idea is welcomed. Thanks.

---

**Edit:**
$A$ is positive semi-definite matrix.

I think this problem is related to transform a matrix into one with constant diagonal elements.

Comment: Do you assume proved [the main theorem of spectral decomposition of hermitian matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem)? Any hermitian matrix A can be written $A = UDU^*$ with U unitary and D diagonal and real. Or is it the question?

Comment: @Edouardb I do know the spectral decomposition of hermitian matrices and tried proving the problem starting from this theorem. However, I failed to connect them in further derivation.

Comment: I think you should have a look at the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) of a hermitian matrix. If $A$ is only semi-definite, the decomposition still exists if you allow non-zero element on the diagonal of the Cholesky matrix, this may be the purpose of multiplying $A$ by $r$ (because the trace is invariant by similitude).

Comment: @Edouardb Thank you for the information about Cholesky decomposition. I will look into it since it seems useful.

Comment: No worries. And you were right, there is no way to directly apply spectral decomposition.